# Will this computer case fan power a lightbulb?

Tags: dc, brushless-dc-motor, power-generation

I'm attempting to help my daughter build a wind generation model for her science fair. I've found some prebuilt kits but the shipping is more than the product. Doing some research it seems she can build her own using a DC motor. A brushless DC motor seems like the best option. This [Insignia 80mm PC Case Cooling Fan](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/insignia-insignia-80mm-pc-case-cooling-fan-black-ns-pcf8050-c/10289689.aspx?path=d6b3d893288337b513ee110fdc6edfeden02) looks like it would work for the project.

Question is, will this produce enough to light a small LED bulb? I'm not entirely sure how to figure that part out.

If this is too broad or of-topic please let me know.

Comment: Without stripping the electronics out of the boss in the middle of the fan, probably not. It'll generate power, but the fan motor controller isn't designed to allow generation, so won't let that power out. Some surgery required ... or get a DC motor out of a dead toy.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I was thinking of getting a cheap RC toy, but also wasn't sure if they had DC or AC motors. They don't always say on the box.

Comment: If it's AC motor(induction motor),it's very difficult to generate energy out of a wind.You have to spin beyond synchronous speed to get energy.Better to use a DC motor.

Comment: Small DC motors are cheap and widely available, but you need a brushed (commutating) one.

Comment: Anything motor in something that is battery operated will be either a brushed or brushless DC motor. A brushed motor is less expensive and most likely to be found in something inexpensive. If a brushless motor is found in an RC toy the electronics will most likely to be external. If you have a fan like the one pictured, it is not too difficult to bypass the electronics, but you need to be able to figure out where the coils are connected.

Comment: You don't want to screw around with digging motors out of devices. Go to Sayal and grab one of those wind generation kits they have. Or one of their brushed DC motors and a blade set if you insist on going that route.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sayal looks like a great site, thanks. I grabbed a cheap $15 toy and a multi-meter. If I can't get an output I'll have to see if they can rush me the parts.

Comment: No, it's pretty terrible. It's just one of the few places up here you can find all sorts of kits.

Comment: I was able to power the LED using the motor from a cheap $15 dollar RC toy by putting a small propeller on it and a can of compressed air. Id' still like to try the computer fan though as outlined by @autistic as I think it is a better base to build from. Thanks for all the input, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the DC computer fans that I have seen are brushless .They use a pushpull CT winding with the CT connected to B+ and each side going to B- via a NPN BJT .If you get into the fan like others have said you can lift the two sides of the winding and place two diodes ,one in each side ,going to B-.If you put the fan back together and blow hard onto the blades you will see a voltage on a DVM .I used BYV1040 diodes on my experiment .Any low drop diode would produce the same result .If the fan spins fast enough it will easily power a LED.

Comment: Where did you buy that diode? I can get it from aliexpress.com, but it won't ship in time. I have 3 weeks or so and shipping from China can take 5+ at times. I wonder if The Source would carry this?

Comment: The Source no longer carries diodes. I think the only discretes they still sell are resistors and LEDs, and only in badly-overpriced bundles.

Comment: @agrothe: Just remembered [these guys](http://www.dipmicro.com/store/). I recommend picking out a few things though, to get your shipping charge's worth.

Comment: I stated the diode that I used and it worked .There is not anything critical about the diode .Any 40V 1 A schottkey would be OK .

Comment: so long as you don't blow too hard the diode is not needed just connect the LED to two of the wires.